# How to make a Discord Bot(Javascript) check if a role exist and create if not

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make so a bot will check if a role called "Mod" exist and if not to create it?

Comment: I think if you get the bot to look at the roles that already exist, then you can check if the one you want doesn't exist, then have the bot create it if needed.

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of existing Stack Overflow questions similar to the one you have posted. You can also check the official DJS guide.

Comment: You have to check the collection of roles in a guild then use the find method to search for a role with the name of "Mod"

Comment: Use  `if else statement` with your `roles.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
    //Get role by name
    
    const mod_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
     (role) => role.name === 'Mod'
    );
    
    // If the mod role doesn't exists here we will create it
    if (!mod_role)
     message.guild.roles.create({
data: {
    name: 'Mod',
    color: 'Some color',
  },
  reason: 'Some reason',
}
```